# Merging two queries to get a single result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, percentage

I have the following two codes, I need to get the percentage by dividing the 'for_2018_19' by the 'total'. I don't know how to merge them and get a single result which is the percentage.

```
select sum(maternities) as total from merged
where City = 'Jeza' and Group = 'Unknown';

select sum(Maternities) as for_2018_19 from merged
where Year = '2016/17') percentage ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use bth query as the only give back single data, as subqueries

But yu should keep in mind that group is a reserved word, and you should avoid it

```
SELECT
(select sum(maternities)  from merged
where City = 'Jeza' and `Group` = 'Unknown')/
(select sum(Maternities)  from merged
where Year = '2016/17') as percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

```
select 
    -- divide partial sum by total
    sum(if(Year = '2016/17', maternities, 0)) / 
    sum(if((City = 'Jeza' and `Group` = 'Unknown'),  maternities, 0))
from merged;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
select sum(Maternities)*100.0/(select sum(maternities) as total from merged
where City = 'Jeza' and Group = 'Unknown') as percent from merged
where Year = '2016/17'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select b.for_2018_19 / a.total
from ( select sum(maternities) as total 
       from merged
       where City = 'Jeza' 
       and Group = 'Unknown' ) a
, (    select sum(Maternities) as for_2018_19 
       from merged
       where Year = '2016/17'
  ) b
```

Comment: this is a good pattern for this problem - not sure why the downvote.. OP please try.